# How to rotate x axis labels 45 degrees

Tags: r, bar-chart, axis-labels

I have some data as of below:

```
mydata <- rbind(c(5,4,3,7,6),
                c(1,4,5,2,2))
colnames(mydata) <- c("Ali","Bala","Chun Li","Danny","Esther")
```

And I would like to do a grouped bar plot of my data:

```
x <- barplot(mydata, beside=T, las=2,
            col=c("yellow2", "brown2"),
            main="Chocolates Eaten by Students",
            ylab="No. of chocolates")
legend("topright", cex=0.7,
       legend = c("White", "Dark"), 
       fill = c("yellow2", "brown2"))
```

[image]

How can I rotate the x axis labels 45 degrees clockwise (from the current positions)?

**Note**: Using the following did not give me the output I want.

```
text(cex=1, x=x+0.5, y=0, colnames(mydata), xpd=TRUE, srt=45, pos=2)
```

Comment: @CathG `x <- barplot()` I guess OP didn't copy the right line. But this question is clearly a duplicate.

Comment: just do `x <- barplot(mydata, beside=T, las=2,col=c("yellow2", "brown2"),main="Chocolates Eaten by Students",ylab="No. of chocolates", names=rep("", ncol(mydata))) ; legend("topright", cex=0.7, legend = c("White", "Dark"), fill = c("yellow2", "brown2")); text(cex=1, x=x[1,]+0.5, y=0, colnames(mydata), xpd=TRUE, srt=45, adj=1)`

Comment: @CathG You need `colMeans(x)+0.5`.

Comment: @Pascal, no I don't, there is only 2 lines, first line is giving the position of first bars, second line is giving position of 2nd bars, those 2 postions are separated by 1 unit so first position + 0.5 gives the middle of the 2 bars. (If there were more than 2 bars, then colMeans would give the result. (But just colMeans, no `+0.5`)

Comment: @CathG Yes. But I prefer the `colmneans` solution, anyway. (without +0.5)

Comment: @Pascal I agree, I proposed this because it was just a tiny modification from the OP's line

Comment: @Pascal Sorry about the duplicate guys and thanks for the inputs!